# How to calculate cumulative profit of a trades list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, finance, algorithmic-trading

Here is a ETH/USDT trades history, I want to calculate the cumulative profit:

```
import pandas as pd
data_list = [('2022-01-29T01:41:43.584Z', 'buy', 2540.87, 0.0079, 20.072873),
 ('2022-01-31T02:01:09.263Z', 'buy', 2508.31, 0.004, 10.03324),
 ('2022-01-31T16:52:18.583Z', 'sell', 2661.75, 0.0118, 31.40865),
 ('2022-01-31T16:52:20.050Z', 'buy', 2661.02, 0.0076, 20.223752),
 ('2022-02-01T13:55:31.912Z', 'sell', 2799.67, 0.0075, 20.997525),
 ('2022-02-01T13:55:34.240Z', 'buy', 2796.45, 0.0072, 20.13444),
 ('2022-02-01T14:47:48.266Z', 'buy', 2760.61, 0.0037, 10.214257),
 ('2022-02-02T14:43:07.346Z', 'buy', 2721.98, 0.0041, 11.160118),
 ('2022-02-02T14:50:35.116Z', 'buy', 2700.0, 0.0095, 25.65),
 ('2022-02-02T15:03:56.623Z', 'buy', 2683.36, 0.0046, 12.343456),
 ('2022-02-02T16:07:34.678Z', 'buy', 2644.73, 0.0051, 13.488123),
 ('2022-02-03T10:02:27.212Z', 'buy', 2606.1, 0.0057, 14.85477),
 ('2022-02-04T08:00:38.711Z', 'sell', 2844.67, 0.0303, 86.193501)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data_list, columns=['dt','side','price','amount','cost'])
```

What I expect is:

```
                          dt  side    price  amount       cost  cumulative_profit
0   2022-01-29T01:41:43.584Z   buy  2540.87  0.0079  20.072873  0
1   2022-01-31T02:01:09.263Z   buy  2508.31  0.0040  10.033240  0
2   2022-01-31T16:52:18.583Z  sell  2661.75  0.0118  31.408650  1.55
3   2022-01-31T16:52:20.050Z   buy  2661.02  0.0076  20.223752  1.55
4   2022-02-01T13:55:31.912Z  sell  2799.67  0.0075  20.997525  
5   2022-02-01T13:55:34.240Z   buy  2796.45  0.0072  20.134440
6   2022-02-01T14:47:48.266Z   buy  2760.61  0.0037  10.214257
7   2022-02-02T14:43:07.346Z   buy  2721.98  0.0041  11.160118
8   2022-02-02T14:50:35.116Z   buy  2700.00  0.0095  25.650000
9   2022-02-02T15:03:56.623Z   buy  2683.36  0.0046  12.343456
10  2022-02-02T16:07:34.678Z   buy  2644.73  0.0051  13.488123
11  2022-02-03T10:02:27.212Z   buy  2606.10  0.0057  14.854770
12  2022-02-04T08:00:38.711Z  sell  2844.67  0.0303  86.193501
```

The result of cumulative_profit 1.55 is calculated by:

```
# current average price
(2540.87*0.0079+2508.31*0.004)/(0.0079+0.004) = 2529.9254621848736

# cumulative profit
(2661.75 - 2529.9254621848736) * 0.0118 = 1.5555295462184915
```

Is there any way to calculate the cumulative_profit?

Comment: why is the second entry in cumulative profit 0? isn't it -0.130240?

Comment: @enke  if you don't sell it, the profit is 0. it's only calculate the completed trade pairs.

Answer (score 2):

You could construct a "profit" column with the formula used to derive 1.55:

```
df['profit'] = (( ( df['price'] - 
                   ( (df['price'] * df['amount']).cumsum() / 
                    df['amount'].cumsum() ).shift() ) * 
                 df['amount'] ).fillna(0))
```

or using chained methods:

```
df['profit'] = (df['price'].mul(df['amount']).cumsum()
                .div(df['amount'].cumsum())
                .shift()
                .rsub(df['price'])
                .mul(df['amount'])
                .fillna(0))
```

Output:

```
                          dt  side    price  amount       cost    profit
0   2022-01-29T01:41:43.584Z   buy  2540.87  0.0079  20.072873  0.000000
1   2022-01-31T02:01:09.263Z   buy  2508.31  0.0040  10.033240 -0.130240
2   2022-01-31T16:52:18.583Z  sell  2661.75  0.0118  31.408650  1.555530
3   2022-01-31T16:52:20.050Z   buy  2661.02  0.0076  20.223752  0.497499
4   2022-02-01T13:55:31.912Z  sell  2799.67  0.0075  20.997525  1.411619
5   2022-02-01T13:55:34.240Z   buy  2796.45  0.0072  20.134440  1.070020
6   2022-02-01T14:47:48.266Z   buy  2760.61  0.0037  10.214257  0.331197
7   2022-02-02T14:43:07.346Z   buy  2721.98  0.0041  11.160118  0.181297
8   2022-02-02T14:50:35.116Z   buy  2700.00  0.0095  25.650000  0.179254
9   2022-02-02T15:03:56.623Z   buy  2683.36  0.0046  12.343456 -0.002774
10  2022-02-02T16:07:34.678Z   buy  2644.73  0.0051  13.488123 -0.199880
11  2022-02-03T10:02:27.212Z   buy  2606.10  0.0057  14.854770 -0.427979
12  2022-02-04T08:00:38.711Z  sell  2844.67  0.0303  86.193501  5.118400
```